# Error - com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: memory exhausted near

Tags: java, mysql, sap-commerce-cloud

What mysql cofig do I need to adjust to resolve this error?

```
The underlying MySQL Exception is 
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: memory exhausted near 'item_t1 ON  item_t1.p_syncjob =0 AND  item_t1.p_targetversion =8796126216793 AND' at line 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
```

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600415/mysql-memory-exhausted-error

Comment: please add some code what you have tried so far ?

Comment: what is your Query, you have a problem in your Query so post your query.

Comment: how many records are you processing