# How do I tell what is using most memory in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My MySQL server is running out of physical memory and is beginning to use swap.  How do I tell what is using the most memory?  Ideally, it would be a specific table or group of indices and I could optimize just a small number of items.

My DB is over 100GB and my current machine has 15GB memory.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using InnoDB storage engine, check your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` variable. I'll go out on a limb and assume you have assigned most of your memory for innodb_buffer_pool and the remainder of the processes are struggling to get some ram to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178736/mysql-maximum-memory-usage/3987796#3987796

Answer (score 6):

> MySQL's maximum memory usage very much depends on hardware, your
>   settings **and** the database itself.
>
> ### Hardware
>
> The hardware is the obvious part. The more RAM the merrier, faster
>   disks *ftw*. Don't believe those monthly or weekly news letters
>   though. MySQL doesn't scale linear - not even on Oracle hardware. It's
>   a little trickier than that.
>
> The bottom line is: there is no general rule of thumb for what is
>   recommend for **your** MySQL setup. It all depends on the current
>   usage or the projections.
>
> ### Settings & database
>
> MySQL offers countless variables and switches to optimize its
>   behavior. If you run into issues, you really need to sit down and read
>   the (f'ing) manual.
>
> As for the database -- a few important constraints:
>
> - table engine (`InnoDB`, `MyISAM`, ...)  * size  * indices  * usage
>
> Most MySQL tips on stackoverflow will tell you about 5-8 so called
>   important settings. First off, not all of them matter - e.g.
>   allocating a lot of resources to InnoDB and not using InnoDB doesn't
>   make a lot of sense because those resources are wasted.
>
> Or - a lot of people suggest to up the `max_connection` variable --
>   well, little do they know it also implies that MySQL will allocate
>   more resources to cater those `max_connections` -- if ever needed. The
>   more obvious solution might be to close the database connection in
>   your DBAL or to lower the `wait_timeout` to free those threads.
>
> If you catch my drift -- there's really a lot, lot to read up on and
>   learn.
>
> #### Engines
>
> Table engines are a pretty important decision, many people forget
>   about those early on and then suddenly find themselves fighting with a
>   30 GB sized `MyISAM` table which locks up and blocks their entire
>   application.
>
> I don't mean to say *MyISAM sucks*, but `InnoDB` can be tweaked to
>   respond almost or nearly as fast as `MyISAM` and offers such thing as
>   row-locking on `UPDATE` whereas `MyISAM` locks the entire table when
>   it is written to.
>
> If you're at liberty to run MySQL on your own infrastructure, you
>   might also want to check out the [percona server](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-server/) because among
>   including a lot of contributions from companies like Facebook and
>   Google (they know fast), it also includes Percona's own drop-in
>   replacement for `InnoDB`, called `XtraDB`.
>
> See my gist for percona-server (and -client) setup (on Ubuntu):
>   http://gist.github.com/637669
>
> #### Size
>
> Database size is very, very important -- believe it or not, most
>   people on the Intarwebs have never handled a large and write intense
>   MySQL setup but those do really exist. Some people will troll and say
>   something like, "Use PostgreSQL!!!111", but let's ignore them for now.
>
> The bottom line is: judging from the size, decision about the hardware
>   are to be made. You can't really make a 80 GB database run fast on 1 
>   GB of RAM.
>
> #### Indices
>
> It's not: the more, the merrier. Only indices needed are to be set and
>   usage has to be checked with `EXPLAIN`. Add to that that MySQL's
>   `EXPLAIN` is really limited, but it's a start.
>
> #### Suggested configurations
>
> About these `my-large.cnf` and `my-medium.cnf` files -- I don't even
>   know who those were written for. Roll your own.
>
> ### Tuning primer
>
> A great start is the [tuning primer](http://forge.mysql.com/projects/project.php?id=44). It's a bash script (hint:
>   you'll need linux) which takes the output of `SHOW VARIABLES` and
>   `SHOW STATUS` and wraps it into hopefully useful recommendation. If
>   your server has ran some time, the recommendation will be better since
>   there will be data to base them on.
>
> The tuning primer is not a magic sauce though. You should still read
>   up on all the variables it suggests to change.
>
> ### Reading
>
> I really like to recommend the [mysqlperformanceblog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com). It's a great
>   resource for all kinds of MySQL-related tips. And it's not just MySQL,
>   they also know a lot about the right hardware or recommend setups for
>   AWS, etc.. These guys have years and years of experience.
>
> Another great resource is [planet-mysql](http://planet.mysql.com/), of course.

This answer is referenced from a similar question on stackoverflow regarding Mysql Memory Usage: [MySQL maximum memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178736/mysql-maximum-memory-usage)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the results of a `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` query or turn on [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html) to pinpoint the slower queries.

Comment: Does slow query always equal to using most memory?  I have some update and lookup queries that use the primary key running very slow.  Thanks.