# mySQL query in PHP only takes 7 columns

Tags: php, mysql

How come my mySQL query will only take 7 columns? Every time I attempt to add an 8th column name, the page breaks. Example:

**Does NOT work:**

```
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, fibre, sugar, img, kcal, carbs, protein, fat FROM table");
        $names = array();
        $fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $names[] = $row;
          }
        } else {
          echo "0 results";
        }
```

**Does Work:** See 'fat' removed from query

```
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, fibre, sugar, img, kcal, carbs, protein FROM table");
        $names = array();
        $fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $names[] = $row;
          }
        } else {
          echo "0 results";
        }
```

I have also tried with different column names from the table, but it doesn't matter, they still don't work. Yes, the columns are all spelled right.

Is there any way I can query more then 7 column names? **ALSO**: using `mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table");` Does not work either!?!? What is going on here??

Comment: I didn't get it. I see `fat`column in both of snippet codes...

Comment: Also, if you are seeing blank pages, check php_error_log or add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beggining of you file.

Comment: *"the page breaks"* - What does that translate to?

Comment: Try integrating this function somehow: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Add `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()` see what that says.

Comment: When OP said _the page breaks_, I guess that 'page' doesn't work... 'Its broken'... lol

Comment: @bcesars Saying "the page breaks" or "it's broken" does not help anyone determine *what* is broken.

Comment: ♫ *When the levee breaks* ♫ @bcesars now that's a good "break" ;-) Google that.

Comment: I know @Mike. that's why I'm laughing. It's too broad saying that something _is broken_ out of the blue and now I suggested to add error in that file.

Comment: @Fred-ii-. YEAH, that is a really nice one...  =D

Comment: You still haven't told us what "the page breaks" means. [Did you do this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521241/mysql-query-in-php-only-takes-7-columns#comment47197441_29521241) or [this?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) just like [this person wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521241/mysql-query-in-php-only-takes-7-columns#comment47197343_29521241)

Comment: @bcesars my apologies, I accidently copied the wrong code. It is updated now. Will try `error_reporting`, thanks. Yes, blank pages is what I was referring to, sorry for using very vague words.

Comment: Blank pages means syntax errors without error reporting set or displayed.

Comment: I don't understand why I would get a syntax error if all I do is add an additional column name to my query...

Comment: Meaning.... you're getting a syntax error now?

Comment: I don't know... I thought that's what you meant with the blank pages... I added bcesars code: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the very beginning of my file inside the php tags and still, nothing comes up on the blank page...

Comment: @McLean25 You could also check your php's error logs. The default with Apache on Linux is usually `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: Ok... here's a very very wild guess as to what could be going on, but I doubt it. First, see if your column name doesn't accidentally contain a space or encoded character. Try to rename the column to say... `fat_x`. If it works, then my "wild guess" is that, in computer code language; FAT has a special meaning "FIle Allocation Table". Again, a very *wild* guess.

Comment: @Mike thanks, finally found the error logs and it told me what the problem is. `[08-Apr-2015 17:49:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5 bytes) in `. Can't believe this is happening as I am trying to display very small content, like 9 text fields for 10 items...

Comment: @Fred-ii- If `fat` had a special meaning in MySQL it would probably appear in the [reserved words list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: @McLean25 Add that to the question and I'll remove my downvote

Comment: @Mike I know. That's why I said *but I doubt it* and *a very wild guess*. ;-) stranger things have happened.

Comment: `ini_set('memory_limit','16M');` or use a higher number. See also http://www.ewhathow.com/2013/09/how-to-increase-mysql-memory-limit/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/12104185/

Comment: @Mike and Fred -ii- : Thanks guys for your help. Sorry for the confusion in the question, just started with PHP over the weekend.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It looks like the memory limit is already set to 128MB. I doubt increasing it would fix the problem. It's probably some sort of memory leak, like an infinite loop.

Comment: @Mike Maybe there's something in the two links that will help the OP.

Comment: @Mike that's what I was thinking as well. I'll just have to go over my code again. I'm sure I have an inefficient loop somewhere.

Comment: Sidenote: Is your table properly indexed?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes problem solved, somewhat. I now know what I have to fix in my code.

Comment: Great. You can post your own answer if you want; Stack lets you do that. I'm glad this matter was finally resolved, *cheers*

Comment: Plus, it could be that if your table isn't indexed, it could be working too hard, in turn taking up more memory.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Reading about 'Properly indexed' tables now. Although I think the majority of the problem was that my table had thousands of rows. I set `LIMIT 10` and that solved my problem for now.

Answer (score 1):

Was trying to pull too much data from the table:

Found in PHP error logs: `[08-Apr-2015 17:49:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5 bytes)`.

Code had to be looked over again to find inefficiencies in loops.

Also added `LIMIT 10` to the end of the query to reduce table workload.

Comment: *"@Fred-ii- Reading about 'Properly indexed' tables now. Although I think the majority of the problem was that my table had thousands of rows. I set LIMIT 10 and that solved my problem for now."* - There's "always" a solution. Just needed to get right "formulae" ;-)

Comment: Plus, you could also use pagination, if that's part of the *ultimate goal* along with the LIMIT.