# mysql terminated with status 1?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, apparmor

This morning I noticed that my mysql server was not running. A look at the logs and I found the information below. While it is troubling that the mysqld service ran out of memory and was killed, it is more troubling that mysql could not restart.

Any ideas on why mysql could not respawn? How can I test to make sure that if the process is killed it will respawn?

Thank you.

```
387 Oct 10 06:37:09 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [12218775.475042] Out of memory: Kill process 810 (mysqld) score 232 or sacrifice child
388 Oct 10 06:37:09 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [12218775.475060] Killed process 810 (mysqld) total-vm:888108kB, anon-rss:139816kB, file-rss:0kB
389 Oct 10 06:37:09 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [12218775.655663] init: mysql main process (810) killed by KILL signal
390 Oct 10 06:37:09 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [12218775.655745] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
391 Oct 10 06:37:10 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [12218776.044805] type=1400 audit(1381408630.181:13): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=27754 comm="apparmor_parser"
392 Oct 10 06:37:10 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [12218776.676434] init: mysql main process (27763) terminated with status 1
393 Oct 10 06:37:10 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [12218776.676489] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
394 Oct 10 06:37:11 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [12218777.468923] init: mysql post-start process (27764) terminated with status 1
395 Oct 10 06:37:11 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [12218777.512363] type=1400 audit(1381408631.649:14): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=27800 comm="apparmor_parser"
396 Oct 10 06:37:11 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [12218777.681433] init: mysql main process (27804) terminated with status 1
397 Oct 10 06:37:11 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx kernel: [12218777.681491] init: mysql respawning too fast, stopped
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1475798

looping script issue probably

Answer (score 3):

I would try running `mysqld` directly as a command, and looking at the output. It could be e.g. [InnoDB corruption leading to stopping immediately after spawning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706106/mysql-innodb-stop-working-on-linode-server/36428081#36428081), at which point `upstart` might try to respawn until `apparmour` stops it.

Answer (score 0):

An old question but a recurrent issue. The question has two faces:

- first, why the mysql process runs out of memory?
- secondly, why the mysql process can't start again?

The first one is something addressed to an overkill in the configuration. An oversized buffer configuration can make mysql ask for more memory than the system can provide. Verify [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178736/mysql-maximum-memory-usage) to get insights of how to find best fit for your environment.

The second issue could be very trickful. There are lot of possibilities for problems that can prevent mysql to start. The following steps can be performed to figure out what is the cause. 
The first clue can be found in the mysql log error file, in most of cases found in /var/log/mysql/error.log
However, regardless the nature of the issue, the error log file can be empty. In this case try to:

1. look into syslog: in a terminal prompt

   ```
   type tail -f /var/log/syslog
   ```

   and in another terminal try to start mysql:

   ```
   service start mysql
   ```

If this approach don't provide any useful clue try the following:

2. Start mysqld from raw in verbose mode:

   ```
   su mysql
   mysqld -v
   ```

as showed [here](http://www.dangtrinh.com/2014/05/mysqld-did-not-start-properly-and-how.html).

The output messages can be helpful to find out the root cause that prevents mysql to start.