# Unable to start mysql on EC2 instance, I keep receiving apparmor error

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-ec2

I am unable to start mysql on my EC2 instance. Receiving following errors

> Oct 28 05:21:08 ip-172-30-1-66 kernel: [  841.115678] init: mysql main process (19029) terminated with status 7
>       Oct 28 05:21:08 ip-172-30-1-66 kernel: [  841.115687] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
>       Oct 28 05:21:09 ip-172-30-1-66 kernel: [  842.011098] init: mysql post-start process (19030) terminated with status 1
>       Oct 28 05:21:09 ip-172-30-1-66 kernel: [  842.016704] type=1400 audit(1540704069.482:278): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=19084 comm="apparmor_parser"

This is on an Ubuntu system

```
# uname -a

Linux ip-172-30-1-66 3.13.0-91-generic #138-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 17:00:34 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql terminated with status 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299950/mysql-terminated-with-status-1)

Comment: I replaced my.cnf with working server my.cnf and it started working. I need to check what is different.