# How can I reduce Xampp mysqld memory usage

Tags: mysql

Well i've set myself to learn php and mysql, bought a book installed XAMPP inside a virtual machine. However i was thinking mysql wouldnt use that much memory, but it uses 500Mb.
And i have not even created anything in it, i'm not sure if thats normal.
I had choosen the Xampp light setup, since my only interest here is Php and mysql.

My goal is just to create a few simple databases with a web interface.
And i'm at the first steps of learning php
I'm not new to programming, i know a long list of computer languages
However i am new to mysql and php appache.

Can someone tell me what to do to reduce memory of mysql ?.
As currently i run into problems, the host running the virtual machine is not that heavy

Comment: you could start by read the mysql docs and looking up the config options for setting memory limits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in the (windows) installer of MySQL which could be also used in xampp.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68287

Try looking for `table_definition_cache` in `my.cnf` and lower this to ~ 200

Answer (score 0):

If you're not storing anything in it as you said, then the 500MB isn't for the 'MYSQL' process but it's for the whole XAMPP thing.

Long story short, this is the Mysql configuration file path :

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

in this file you can find :

```
key_buffer              = 8M
max_connections         = 30
query_cache_size        = 8M
query_cache_limit       = 512K
thread_stack            = 128K
```

This is the MAXIMUM memory the Mysql is using.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i was thinking mysqld.exe is the process of mysql which consumes 500mb here, but you say the process includes php appache and mysql.. isnt that still a bit large?, or did i had a wrong idea about it. I was thinking those where minimized services no extra's

Comment: @user219279 i don't think that the mysqld.exe can reach 500mb, i have a plenty of database... and only 10mb is used, 
mysqld is just the process for running mysql, i thought you were speaking about the whole xampp process

Comment: no its just mysqld at around 500mb (i see it in taskmanager) / resource monitor memory usage. something must be wrong here, but i dont know what

Comment: i ffound this 

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178736/mysql-maximum-memory-usage)

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql in xampp 400mb cpu
```

You add in `php.ini` two line end :

```
[mysqld]

table_definition_cache = 400
```

I sure with you :) .

Comment: since it is an answer to an old question could you please add more details ? What is the innovation factor of your answer comparing to the old one already accepted ?