# Not able to Insert more than 33138 Rows in MySql table

Tags: mysql, row

I have created table in MySql in Memory, but after inserting 33138 it throws an exception "table is full"

Syntax -
create table Employee(name varchar(500) null) max_rows = 1000000  ENGINE=Memory;

I have also alter the table max row limit but problem still exits.
Syntax -
alter table employee max_rows = 1000000, avg_row_length=50;

[image]

Comment: You should have a look at the `max_heap_table_size system variable`. *The maximum size of MEMORY tables is limited by the max_heap_table_size system variable, which has a default value of 16MB. To enforce different size limits for MEMORY tables, change the value of this variable.* Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/memory-storage-engine.html

Answer (score 0):

`I have created table in MySql in Memory`   and `throws an exception "table is full"`

Its very very likely your out of memory, if you have memory left on the machine, You have hit the mysql memory limit

[MySQL maximum memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178736/mysql-maximum-memory-usage)  has more information