# Force Mysql to use more memory

Tags: php, mysql, digital-ocean

I resized a digital ocean instance from 512mb to 16GB of ram, but my mysql only seems to use 1GB, even with hundreds of active users on the website (according to new relic).

What specific settings do I need to change to get the best performance from this larger instance?

Comment: Related: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178736/mysql-maximum-memory-usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178736/mysql-maximum-memory-usage)

Comment: You might look in to replacing MySQL with MariaDB.  It is a drop-in replacement that is a fork of MySQL, and is being developed by MySQL's original developers.  Changeout is a snap, (actual drop-in replacement in every respect), and it has many performance and scalability improvements that MySQL does not.  I've done this for 4 separate heavy-load implementations, and I've been very happy with it.  You'll still want to look at Kenny's link, as many of the manual improvements still apply.