# Doctrine setParameter makes MySQL error

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

This is my SQL query in Doctrine:

```
 ->andwhere("f.yearEvents LIKE :yearEvents")
 ->setParameter("yearEvents", $param)
```

When param has more than 10 signs, I get this error:

> General error: 2008 MySQL client ran out of memory

When param has less than 10 signs everything works just fine!

Anyone have an idea? I can't figure out where the problem is. My DB is small.

Comment: Not a MySQL guy, but it looks like this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178736/mysql-maximum-memory-usage

Comment: you could try to add an index on your yearEvents field

Comment: Try to look at generated SQL: $qb->getQuery()->getSQL() and run it directly